# Change the width/height given of embed/html iframe from vimeo api objects

Tags: html, css, angularjs, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

All the video objects that is loaded have the width set to 1200 and height to 720, How would I go about to change this?

ex:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/155086124?badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0" width="1280" height="720" frameborder="0"  webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Is there a way to override the height and width, or straight up edit the api objects after grabbing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override width and height by css:

```
iframe {
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
}
```